# How to calculate the value of a sum which is similar to a Jacobi theta function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, theta-functions

I would like to know the value of the following infinite series:
$$\vartheta^*_3(q,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz},$$
which is very similar to the definition of $\vartheta_3$ in [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html). Except $\vartheta^*_3$ is the sum from $n=0$ to $\infty$ whereas $\vartheta_3$ is taken over $n=-\infty$ to $\infty$. Is there an analytic solution for this sum?

Comment: This is what is called a "partial theta function". There are several papers including this term in the title.

Comment: I found [this](https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/OleWarnaar/pubs/Partial-thetas.pdf) paper. Equation (1.1) says that $$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nq^{n(n-1)/2}(a^n+b^n)=(q)_\infty(a)_\infty(b)_\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(ab/q)_{2n}q^n}{(q)_n(a)_n(b)_n(ab)_n},$$ the trouble with this is that it still involves a sum. Why is the sum on rhe right-hand side of this equation prefereable to the one on the left?

Comment: Okay. That looks like a Ramanujan q-series identity. Ramanujan worked in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomplete answer : The real part of the series.
$$\text{Real part}\qquad Re\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 q^{n^2}e^{2niz}\right)=Re\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}\right)$$
$$\text{Imaginary part}\qquad Im\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 q^{n^2}e^{2niz}\right)=-Im\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}\right)$$
$$\vartheta_3(q,z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 q^{n^2}e^{2niz}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}-q^{0^2}e^{2*0*iz}$$
$$\vartheta_3(q,z)=2Re\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}\right)- 1$$
$$Re\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}\right)=\frac12\left(\vartheta_3(q,z)+1\right) $$

Comment: Thank you, this may well be the best we can do. Unfortunately, I would like to know the value of the imaginary part as well.